# How to get the content of a XML node as text

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
    <a>
     <y>
      This is <b>text</b>
      <c>stuff</c>
     </y>
     <d>
       This is super <em>code</em>, and we like it ! <b>FOObarr</b> !
     </d>
    </a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($xml as $node) {
    //use another function than asXML, to get some more magic
    echo $node->asXML();
    echo "\n--\n";
}
?>
```

I want to output this:

```
      This is <b>text</b>
      <c>stuff</c>
--
      This is super <em>code</em>, and we like it ! <b>FOObarr</b> !
--
```

without the y tags and d tags; but the current code outputs this:

```
<y>
      This is <b>text</b>
      <c>stuff</c>
     </y>
--
<d>
       This is super <em>code</em>, and we like it ! <b>FOObarr</b> !
     </d>
--
```

Note that the tags could be named differently according to input data.

Comment: What does it output? What attempt have you made to filter the output?

Comment: What are you know for that file ?the structure is always the same?

Comment: If you want to embed HTML in an XML document, you should encode it (or wrap it in CDATA). Otherwise, it isn't text content, but child nodes.

Comment: iainn, that is correct: The original data are unfortunately not with CDATA. And that is correct, those are child nodes, but I have to output it nevertheless.

Comment: This is a reasonably common situation, actually, and is sometimes referred to as getting the "innerhtml" or "innertext" of the element. Possibly you can do something by switching to DOM functions with `dom_import_simplexml`, but I can't find a decent duplicate question at the minute.

Comment: @IMSoP - I am surprised as well, to be honest (despite my effort to find a proper answer before even asking the question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
    <a>
     <y>
      This is <b>text</b>
      <c>stuff</c>
     </y>
     <d>
       This is super <em>code</em>, and we like it ! <b>FOObarr</b> !
     </d>
    </a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($xml as $node) {
    $s = trim($node->asXML());
    $s = preg_replace(['#^<[^>]*>#','#<[^>]*>$#'], '', $s);
    $s = trim($s);
    echo $s;
    echo "\n--\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I thought there were easier ways than using preg_replace (by using other XML related PHP functions/objects), but apparently I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

As @iainn says, you're embedding html inside XML without encoding it, so it's going to get a bit messy. But based on your example, you could just navigate one level deeper before echoing, since HTML looks like XML to the decoder.

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
        <a>
         <y>
          This is <b>text</b>
          <c>stuff</c>
         </y>
         <d>
           This is super <em>code</em>
         </d>
        </a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($xml as $node) {
    echo $node;
    foreach($node as $subnode) {
        echo $subnode->asXml();
    }
    echo "\n--\n";
}
?>
```

Produces:

```
      This is 

     <b>text</b><c>stuff</c>
--

       This is super 
     <em>code</em>
--
```

If in practice your data is a bit more complicated or the newlines and other subtleties are important, consider encoding the HTML.

Comment: Good solution, but might be worth noting that this will only work if the element's actual text content comes *before* any child tags. So `<y>Text<b>Blah</b>More text</y>` won't render in order.

Comment: Improved questions as of this answer and comment